# Flattening Nested Observable in object property

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

I am new to RxJs and trying to use it in my node app. Following code expects to return array of objects and each object should have nested array in one of its property.

Now the problem is it returns expected array of Objects, except the inner observable (that is supposed to be an array) is still not flattened in the subscribe.

```
createPlanOffers = (groupPlans) => {
    const groupPlan1 = groupPlans.filter(PREDICATE_1);
    return groupPlans
        .filter(PREDICATE_2)
        .reduce((offers, plan2) => {
            const plans_1 = groupPlan1.filter(PREDICATE_1_1);
            const plan1Details = plans_1.flatMap(plan1 => ({
                id: plan1.ID
            }));
            const offer = {
                groupKey: plan2.KEY,
                plan1Details: plan1Details
            };
            offers.push(offer);
            return offers;
        }, []);
};

const classPlans = query()
    .groupBy(group => group.KEY)
    .flatMap(groupPlans => createPlanOffers(groupPlans))
    .subscribe(group => console.log(group),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('complete'));
```

Expected Result:

```
[
 { groupKey: 1111,
   plan1Details: [{id: xyz}]
 },
 { groupKey: 2222,
   plan1Details: [{id: xyz}]
 },
 { groupKey: 2222,
   plan1Details: [{id: abc}]
 } 
]
```

Actual Result :(

```
[
 { groupKey: 1111,
   plan1Details: 
     Observable {
     _isScalar: false,
     source: [Observable],
     operator: [MergeMapOperator] } },
   { groupKey: 2222,
     plan1Details: 
       Observable {
       _isScalar: false,
       source: [Observable],
       operator: [MergeMapOperator] } },
   { groupKey: 2222,
     plan1Details: 
       Observable {
       _isScalar: false,
       source: [Observable],
       operator: [MergeMapOperator] } } 
]
```

This query will return something like:

```
const query = () => Rx.Observable.from([
    { KEY: 1111,
        id: 'xyz',
        category: 'A', // predicates are using these categories for filters
    }
    { GRGR_CK: 2222,
        id: 'xyz',
        category: 'A',
    }
    { GRGR_CK: 2222,
        id: 'ABC',
        category: 'B',
    }
])
```

Comment: its not throwing any error... and when you subscribe the inner observable within subscribe, it actually gives you the correct data

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are trying to achieve here? Like, given the query, what is the desired output? Particularly on the `PREDICATE_1`  and `PREDICATE_1_1` codes..

Comment: its kind of denormalized data.. query fetches the records from oracle and return in stream. Iam trying to group the data with they key and club them togetha on id (obviously its not the actual data). its  sort of master detail records within one group so this property plan1group holds array of detail record.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `flatMap` does not recursively resolve `Observables` from my understanding. What you could do is add another `flatMap` and resolve the inner one before returning:

```
query()
    .groupBy(group => group.KEY)
    .flatMap(groupPlans => createPlanOffers (groupPlans))
    .flatMap(obj => // could destruct the values you want instead
       obj.plan1Details.map(
         val => Object.assign({}, obj, { plan1Details: val})
       )
    )
    .subscribe(group => console.log(group),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('complete'));
```

I don't like the way that looks/reads so I would look into resolving this higher up but not sure without looking at the full code where.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefinedMergeMapSubscriber.query().groupBy.do.flatMap.do.flatMap.obj [as project].

First flatmap return an array of observables itself. then each element in the array has a property that holds array of  observables itself. This does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your `plan1Details` will be an `Observable`, since you return it as an `Observable` using `.flatMap()`.

Since you have two predicates to filter, of which both are filtered after the grouping, you can use `Observable.forkJoin()` to combine them and transform them on the fly:

```
createPlanOffers = (groupPlans) => {
    const groupPlan1 = groupPlans.filter(PREDICATE_1);
    const groupPlan2 = groupPlans.filter(PREDICATE_2);
    return Observable.forkJoin([groupPlan1,groupPlan2])
        .map(([predicate1,predicate2])=>{
            predicate2.reduce((offers,plan2)=>{
                const offer = {
                    groupKey: plan2.KEY,
                    plan1Details: predicate1.map(plan1=>({id:plan1.ID})) //this map is an JS array.map(), not observable.map()
                };
                offers.push(offer);
                return offers

            },[])
        });
};
```

Note that the `.map()` of `predicate1.map()` is a JavaScript's native `array.map()`, not the `Observable` one.

Comment: This does not work . For.map([predicate1,predicate2]) predicate2 is suppose to filter details from predicate1. but here both will only hold 1 element at a time and we need predicate1 to be an array

Comment: For now I just subscribed to predicate1 and push details into JS array. predicate1.map().subscribe(next => details.push(next))... I would really appreciate if you guys have  a better solution than this